# Splitting a Hashmap into two smaller maps

Tags: java

I have one hashmap with K, V value of  and that I want to split into two subMaps.

> `HashMap<Long,JSONObject>`

One way is this I have found that we can use treemap and do subMapping.

```
TreeMap<Integer, Integer> sorted = new TreeMap<Integer, Integer>(bigMap);

SortedMap<Integer, Integer> zeroToFortyNine = sorted.subMap(0, 50);
SortedMap<Integer, Integer> fiftyToNinetyNine = sorted.subMap(50, 100);
```

But the thing is I am not getting subMap for jsonObject and I want to do it with HashMap only.

Thanks

Comment: what is the criteria to split the `HashMap`? it has no order, so it's not really easy to split it in "half" as half is not defined

Comment: How about using `sorted.entrySet()`? Iterate the HashMap and put the entries to the other two maps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems from your question that you don't care about criteria for spliting, you just want to split it in half. The below solution will work accordingly.
Just create a counter and insert in first half hashmap while counter<(size of original hashmap)/2 and when counter> (size of original hashmap)/2, insert into second half hashmap.

```
HashMap<Integer,JSONObject> hmap;
HashMap<Integer,JSONObject> halfhmap1=new HashMap<>();
HashMap<Integer,JSONObject> halfhmap2=new HashMap<>();
int count=0;

for(Map.Entry<Long, JSONObject> entry : map.entrySet()) {
    (count<(hmap.size()/2) ? halfhmap1:halfhmap2).put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    count++;
}
```

Comment: Seems like the key of the hashmap are increasing integers though

Comment: Can't say for sure

Comment: Sorry, my bad. removed it

Comment: Don't be, @Lino covered the java 8 soution ;) I would have used something like `AtomicBoolean bool = new AtomicBoolean(true);
  map.forEach((k ,v) -> (bool.getAndSet(bool.get() ^ true) ? sub1 : sub2).put(k,v));` myself

Comment: @Lino. No, he alternately puts in sub maps. I am filing map one by one.

Comment: Well, you just have changed the condition ;) You could have kept your previous if-else soluion...

Comment: You can always see who posted answer first. My logic is still the same. I just understood now that there is no need of iterator.

Answer (score 6):

You can make use of the *Java 8 Streaming API*:

```
Map<Long, JSONObject> map = ...;
AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger(0);
Map<Boolean, Map<Long, JSONObject>> collect = map.entrySet()
    .stream()
   .collect(Collectors.partitioningBy(
       e -> counter.getAndIncrement() < map.size() / 2, // this splits the map into 2 parts
       Collectors.toMap(
           Map.Entry::getKey, 
           Map.Entry::getValue
       )
   ));
```

This collects the map into 2 halfes, the first (`map.get(true)`) containing all the elements from below the middle and the second (`map.get(false)`) half containing all the elements from the middle upwards.

Comment: Unless the key are not from 1 to `map.size` but random values. Then you will not split in "equivalent" size map

Comment: @AxelH Thanks for that mention. I've edited the code to use an incrementing counter instead

Comment: I would not have thought to use an atomic counter, you can use an integer one by the way, `map.size` can't hold a `long`.

Comment: @AxelH well in your answer you're distributing the map evenly, whereas i just take the first half into a map and then the other half into another :)

Comment: I agree, but I am not sure if he received a sorted map or not since "_I want to do it with HashMap only._". So for me, the order is not important. Both valid solution in the end, one in `Stream`, on with an iterator. perfect ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you can't use the values or the key to know where to split, simply count the iteration :

```
Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<Long, String> sub1 = new HashMap<>();
Map<Long, String> sub2 = new HashMap<>();

int i = 0;
for(Map.Entry<Long, String> e : map.entrySet()){
    (i++ % 2 == 0 ? sub1:sub2).put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
}
```

I used a ternary to increment the counter and select the map. So it will equally split the values on those two maps.

Test:

```
    Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1L, "foo");
    map.put(2L, "bar");
    map.put(3L, "for");
    map.put(4L, "far");

    Map<Long, String> sub1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Long, String> sub2 = new HashMap<>();

    int i = 0;
    for(Map.Entry<Long, String> e : map.entrySet()){
        (i++ % 2 == 0 ? sub1:sub2).put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }

    System.out.println(sub1);
    System.out.println(sub2);
```

> {1=foo, 3=for}
>   {2=bar, 4=far}

That would be easily adapted to split in 3, 4, or any number of maps if wanted :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Map<Long, String> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put(1L, "foo");
    map.put(2L, "bar");
    map.put(3L, "for");
    map.put(4L, "far");

    Map<Long, String> sub1 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Long, String> sub2 = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Long, String> sub3 = new HashMap<>();

    split(map, sub1, sub2, sub3);

    System.out.println(sub1);
    System.out.println(sub2);
    System.out.println(sub3);
}

@SafeVarargs
public static <T, U> void split(Map<T,U> map, Map<T,U>... array){
    int i = 0;
    for(Map.Entry<T, U> e : map.entrySet()){
        array[i++% array.length].put(e.getKey(), e.getValue());
    }
}
```

> {1=foo, 4=far}
>   {2=bar}
>   {3=for}

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the set of entries and populate two different maps:

```
Map<Long, JSONObject> m = null;
Map<Long, JSONObject> zeroToFortyNine = new HashMap<>();
Map<Long, JSONObject> fiftyToNinetyNine = new HashMap<>();

m.forEach((k, v) -> {
    if(k < 50) {
        zeroToFortyNine.put(k, v);
    } else {
        fiftyToNinetyNine.put(k, v);
    }
});
m.clear();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some of Guava functionalities which allow to partition a collection.

```
Map<Object, Object> map = new HashMap<>();

List<List<Map.Entry<Object, Object>>> list = Lists.newArrayList(Iterables.partition(map.entrySet(), map.size() / 2 + 1));

Map<Object, Object> map1 = list.get(0).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));

Map<Object, Object> map2 = list.get(1).stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split a Map into any number of parts by calculating the number of items per partition ("recordsPerChunk").

The following should work.

```
// number of parts for you is 2
int n = 2;
int size = yourMap.size();

int recordsPerChunk = 
  (size % n == 0) ?
    (size / n) :
     ((size / n) + 1);

// Counter
AtomicInteger ai = new AtomicInteger();

// List with n chunks
Collection chunks = 
    yourMap
       .entrySet()
       .stream()
       .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(it -> ai.getAndIncrement() / recordsPerChunk))
       .values();
```